# select value joined with all values of another table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have a table "materiel" (codeM, DATE_D_ACHAT,DATE_FIN_DE_GAR , ... , ... ,)

```
CODEM              
--------------------
1245                 
25365                
354136               
452486               
53453                
543                  
56354                
8752                 
94685
```

and table "users" (CODEU,NOMU,PRENOMU,...  )

```
CODEU              
--------------------
163458               
354635               
569859               
58454                
65646                
86859
```

and third table "utiliser_le_materiel"

```
    CODEM                CODEU              
-------------------- --------------------
1245                 163458               
25365                163458               
452486               163458               
8752                 163458               
94685                163458               
1245                 354635               
452486               354635               
8752                 354635               
1245                 569859               
452486               569859               
53453                569859               
56354                569859               
8752                 569859               
94685                569859               
1245                 58454                
53453                58454                
56354                58454                
8752                 58454                
1245                 65646                
452486               65646                
56354                65646                
8752                 65646                
1245                 86859                
452486               86859                
8752                 86859
```

i want to select the codeM which is joined with all the codeU...
how can i do it in sql ?

i tried 
"select CODEM from utiliser_le_materiel where codeu in (select codeu from user )"

and this

"SELECT CODEM FROM utiliser_le_materiel GROUP BY CODEM HAVING codeu IN (SELECT Z.CODEU FROM user Z )"

i tried to make it with "MINUS" but i cannot !

Comment: i tried "select CODEM from utiliser_le_materiel where
codeu in (select codeu from user )" and this "SELECT CODEM FROM utiliser_le_materiel GROUP BY CODEM HAVING codeu IN (SELECT Z.CODEU FROM user Z )"

Comment: Can you add your desired result in your question?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track.  But your `having` should look at counts.  Assuming no duplicates in the junction table:

```
SELECT CODEM
FROM utiliser_le_materiel
GROUP BY CODEM
HAVING count(*) = (select count(*) from user);
```